# Using .closest within a table to hide a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a table that expands details on a click of a row. Once a row is clicked, I want the hidden `<tr>` below it to show. I get that working correctly but when I try to hide it again, a white box appears below that I do not want to occur. Here is a fiddle of my example: https://jsfiddle.net/pt0skyyb/

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>+</td>
        <td>First</td>
        <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="child-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First</th>
                        <th>Second</th>
                        <th>Third</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>+</td>
        <td>Third</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="child-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First</th>
                        <th>Second</th>
                        <th>Third</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("table").hide();

    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        var $child = $target.closest('tr.child');
        var $next = $target.closest("tr").next();   
        if ( $child.hasClass("shown")) {
            $child.hide().removeClass("shown");
        } else {
            $next.show().addClass("shown").slideToggle();
        }                    
    });
});
```

If you look at the html, the `<tr>` with class `child` is set to `display:none;` to begin with so it is hidden. Once you click the row to make it appear and then again to disappear, it is not being completely hidden and leaves a white box. I am trying to make it disappear fully as it was before it was clicked.

To do this, I am trying  `$target.closest('tr').find('.child').hide();` to hide it, but I can't get it to work correctly. Right now it is never going inside the if statement that checks to see if the closest `tr.child` is displayed and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `js` to following.

```
$(function () {
    $(".table tr:gt(0)").click(function (event) {
        $(this).next('tr.child').toggle();
    });
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pt0skyyb/2/)**

Comment: That's perfect, can you explain what `tr:gt(0)` is doing?

Comment: Try clicking on the row that appears, and see what happens.

Comment: Sure. [`tr:gt(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) will select the tr's except the first. @user081608

Comment: just change this line `$(this).next('tr.child').toggle();`

Comment: Can you click on the row just revealed? I think that's an undesired behavior which @PietroLerro's tweak should fix.

Comment: As an alternative to `.table tr:gt(0)` you could also use `.table tr:not(:first)` or `.table tr:nth-child(n+2)`. Or even better, change your HMTL mark up and add a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, and change the JS selector to `.table tbody tr`

Comment: @PeterKA Good point, didn't look at that. That is an undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one close to your original also, here is an option:

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("table").hide();

    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest('tr').next('.child').hasClass("shown")) {
            $target.closest('tr').next('.child').hide();
            $target.closest("tr").next('.child').removeClass("shown");
        } else { 
            $target.closest("tr").next().show();
            $target.closest("tr").next().addClass("shown");
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("table").slideDown();
        }                    
    });
});
```

Though honestly I would highly discourage playing around with this event.target stuff. It makes things really confusing and vague. You should make the selector target the desired row specifically.